# Autowire and reuse "Spring-defined" properties

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a simple question but I can't find anything about it in the documentation nor any example.

I have a Spring Boot project which uses RabbitMQ and the Spring boot AMQP module.
I'm using a specific exchange, and the Spring `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` so I need to define my own `RabbitTemplate` bean, I guess (at this point, if anyone knows if it can be done another simpler way, you are welcome).

```
@Bean
RabbitTemplate myAwesomeTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
    rabbitTemplate.setExchange(myBeautifulExchange);
    rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey("legendary");
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

The real question for me here is that I have to define a `CachingConnectionFactory` bean too, just to set it to the template, but it seems a `CachingConnectionFactory` is already defined by the Spring `RabbitAutoConfiguration` class, so I was wondering if I could simply do this in my class:

```
@Autowired
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory
```

But Intellij keeps complaining because it cannot find the definition of that bean, as if it was some definition order matter or something...
When I launch the project that way, it seems ok anyway, but I don't like when Intellij complains, it's like I'm doing something "not the standard way".

Thank you everyone in advance ! Sorry for the long explanation.

PS: same problem if I just want to autowire the Spring `RabbitProperties` bean and use the host, username and password properties (respectively `spring.rabbitmq.host`, `spring.rabbitmq.username` and `spring.rabbitmq.password`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But Intellij keeps complaining because it cannot find the definition ...
>   I don't like when Intellij complains, it's like I'm doing something "not the standard way".

You could try to fool it by adding it to the factory method and using argument injection...

```
@Bean
RabbitTemplate myAwesomeTemplate(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    ...
}
```

Same thing with properties.

Either way (`@Autowired` or this one) is "the standard way".

If it still complains, I suggest you talk to JetBrains.

Comment: So you think it should work this way ?
I already tried to inject it in the bean factory method, but ...same issue, Intellij complains the same way on the method parameter...

Comment: That's the way the framework's designed to be used; I can't speak to the IntelliJ support for it; sorry.

Comment: No problem ! Thank you for the explanation. At least I know now that I'm not doing anything wrong here.